# Eclipse's WTP translation output

Tags: eclipse, jsp, eclipse-wtp, stripes, jspx

How can I view the intermediate translation done to JSP and JSPX pages by WTP?  I'm getting weird syntax errors in my Problems tab of Eclipse in a project that has plenty of .jspx pages.  They don't affect anything in the running application (Tomcat 6.0) and they appeared only over the last 2 weeks, after an update.

The reason why I'd like to view the output is that I'm using the Stripes framework at http://stripesframework.org and the errors disappear for a particular .jspx file after I remove the <stripes:errors /> line of that file.  At the same time, the syntax errors only appeared after I did recent fresh install of Eclipse at work, but then an update of Eclipse at home shortly therafter.  I'd like to see the output to determine whose problem this should be (WTP, Stripes, or maybe just me :).

Remember that this issue is somewhat cosmetic, as it doesn't affect anything functionally.  It simply spams my Problems tab in Eclipse and shows the little red X icons in the project explorer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now you'd have to add the separate automated tests download to do this, and only in the 3.1 branch, but it enables a "Show Translation" command through Ctrl+Shift+9.  Beware that the translation generated isn't 100% the same as the server would create at runtime--it's not intended to be executed.  Also, the most recent 3.0.3 builds contain fixes to the translator that should clear up these kinds of problems (NESTED variables + self-closing tags).  3.0.3 is due in November and should update cleanly into Ganymede SR1.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen the eclipse JSP editor get really confused over almost nothing.  You said the problem goes away if you remove the  tag.  Does it come back if you put the tag back?  I know that Eclipse 3.3 sometimes had some issues with JSP files where opening them, and forcing a save would clear the file of error messages (I haven't tried 3.4 yet).  Maybe that's what's happening to you.  Other than that, do you have all the proper includes / xml namespaces defined in the files?

Answer (score 0):

I'm having exactly same problem with JSP and `<stripes:errors/>` tag in Ganymede. With Europa, there were no errors. Now it displays a couple of weird syntax errors on the problems pane. But as Silvaran stated it's just cosmetic, since the project builds correctly and works. It's still annoying though.